# Is it true with the array representation for storing an n-element heap, the leaves are the nodes indexed by ⌊n/2⌋+1, ⌊n/2⌋+2 … n?

Tags: algorithms

Exercise 6.1-7 of "Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition. The MIT Press, 2009" asks about a proof for

> with the array representation for storing an n-element heap, the leaves are the nodes indexed by ⌊n/2⌋+1, ⌊n/2⌋+2, … , n

For the heap in Figure 6.1, there are 10 elements, so n = 10 and the leaves start at index = 8, pointed out by the red square.

[image]

⌊n/2⌋+1 = 6 is less than 8, which seems conflicts with the statement in the exercise.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are confusing the leaves, i.e. the nodes without children, with the nodes of maximum depth. Here the leaves are the nodes $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$, while the nodes of maximum depth are $\{8,9,10\}$. With the indexing $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ the left child is $L(x)=2x$ and the right child is $R(x)=2x+1$. Due to max-heaps being complete binary trees, a node is a leaf if and only if $L(x)>n$, i.e. if and only if $2x>n$, if and only if $x>\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1 = 5+1 = 6$ in your case. And the leaves are $2,4,1,9,3$, which are indeed placed at indices $6,\dots, 10$ in your array.

Comment: Thank you. Does the leaf "2" in the answer refer to the one I put in the red square? If yes, it seems it indexes 8 rather than 6.

Comment: No, leaf is by definition any node that has degree $1$